# Why is this BigQuery WHERE NOT IN statement giving no results?

Tags: google-bigquery

We would expect that this Google BigQuery query would remove at most 10 rows of results - but this query gives us zero results - despite that table A has thousands of rows all with unique ENCNTR_IDs.

```
SELECT ENCNTR_ID
FROM `project.dataset.table_A`
WHERE ENCNTR_ID NOT IN
(
SELECT ENCNTR_ID
FROM `project.dataset.table_B`
LIMIT 10
)
```

If we make the query self-referential, it behaves as expected: we get thousands of results with just 10 rows removed.

```
SELECT ENCNTR_ID
FROM `project.dataset.table_A`
WHERE ENCNTR_ID NOT IN
(
SELECT ENCNTR_ID
FROM `project.dataset.table_A` # <--- same table name
LIMIT 10
)
```

What are we doing wrong? Why does the first query give us zero results rather than just remove 10 rows of results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution**: Use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN` when dealing with possible nulls:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM UNNEST([1,2,3]) i
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM UNNEST([2,3,null]) i2 WHERE i=i2)

# 1
```

---

Previous guess - which turned out to be the cause:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM UNNEST([1,2,3]) i
WHERE i NOT IN UNNEST([2,3])

# 1
```

vs

```sql
SELECT *
FROM UNNEST([1,2,3]) i
WHERE i NOT IN UNNEST([2,3,null])

# This query returned no results.
```

Are there any nulls in that `project.dataset.table_B`?

Comment: That is unexpected behavior but exactly right. You have been an ever-present BigQuery lifesaver on SO Felipe - I hope Google appreciates you as much as we do!